# Javascript - how to retrieve a key from dictionary in the Object constructor

Tags: javascript, dictionary, constructor, key-value

currently, I am initializing an object and one of its values is retrieved from the dictionary, in simplified form something like this

```
var TrailColor = {
    red: '#FF0000',
    orange: '#FF9900',
    yellow: '#FFFF00' 
};

function Trail(trailName, trailColor) {
    this.trailName = trailName;
    this.trailColor = trailColor;
}

var trail1 = new Trail("TrailName", TrailColor.red);
```

Now I've decided that I want as a part of this object not only the color code, but also a color name. However, I am not sure how to retrieve the color name "inversely" - so I get the one exact key (not the whole array, I know how to get it) depending on the value and put it as a property of the object. Is there some straightforward way to do it, without the need to iterate through the whole array? Thank you.

Comment: so pass in "red" and read the color inside Trail....

Comment: Pass in `red` as a *string* in other words, then `Trail()` gets the name and can use that to perform the dictionary lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd pass the color name instead of the value in the first place:

```
function Trail(name, color = 'red') {
  this.name = name;
  this.colorName = color;
  this.color = this._colors[color];
}

Object.assign(Trail.prototype, {
  _colors: {
    red: '#FF0000',
    orange: '#FF9900',
    yellow: '#FFFF00'
  },
  getColorName() {
    return this.colorName;
  }
});

const trail = new Trail("TrailName", "red");
trail.colorName // => "red"
trail.getColorName() // => "red"     
trail.color // => "#FF0000"
```